# Customising jaxb marshalling output

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

My class is like the following:

```
class Employee {
  private String Code;
      //getter and setter below
}
```

Using jaxb when I marshal I am getting these elements:

```
<employee><code>some value</code></employee>
```

But I want the output to be like:

```
<Employee><Code>some value</Code></Employee>
```

To get above output I changed my code to:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Employee")
class Employee {
      @XmlElement(name = "Myname")
  private String Code;
      //getter and setter below
}
```

When I marshal I am getting output as:

```
<Employee><Code>some value</Code><code>some value</code></Employee>
```

How can I avoid creating `<code>some value</code>`?

Comment: Hi Peter, since you are new to Stack Overflow.  If Pat's answer solved your issue then please consider marking it as "accepted" this indicates to people that you are no longer looking for an answer.  It also helps Pat by increasing his reputation score.

Answer (score 1):

Put the

```
@XmlElement(name = "Code")
```

On the getter method